# ibm_db gem on Ruby 2.3.4 missing dependency

Tags: ruby, db2, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.2.0 on Ruby 2.3.4 to connect to MySQL (via `mysql2` gem)and DB2 (via `ibm_db` gem) databases.

When I attempt to connect to the DB2, I get:

`Error loading the 'ibm_db' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? cannot load such file -- arel/visitors/bind_visitor`

and the trace calls out

`ibm_db (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:13:in`'

which consists of

`require 'arel/visitors/bind_visitor'`

It certainly looks like it's trying to load a dependency, but it's not able to. `bundle install` returns no errors.

I'm not sure how to check that the Bind_Visitors module is installed correctly, or what else might cause this error. Please let me know if you need to see any logs or the Gemfile.

Per request, the connection method.

config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

prms: &prms
  adapter: ibm_db
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  username: <%= ENV["PRMS_USERNAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["PRMS_PASSWORD"] %>
  schema: V10INTRA
  host: 10.11.210.61
  port: 446
  authentication: server

development:
  <<: *default
  database: portal
  host: albireo
  username: <%= ENV["DEV_DB_USERNAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["DEV_DB_PASSWORD"] %>
```

app/models/prms_record.rb:

```
class PrmsRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  # establish_connection :"prms_#{Rails.env}"
  establish_connection :prms
end
```

app/models/location.rb

```
class Location < PrmsRecord
end
```

I'm testing with just a `find_by_sql` call in the controller to select the first 10 rows of a table. As a note, I'm aware there are efficiency issues with connection pooling here, I'm just trying to get the simplest method working before I spend the time making it performant.

Comment: How are you connecting to these 2 different databases? Please post your configurations for this dual connectivity

Comment: I added it to the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the `ibm_db` gem is not compatible with `arel` version 9.0.

`rails` 5.2 relies on `active_record` 5.2 which relies on `arel` version `>= 9.0`.([Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/activerecord.gemspec))

`ibm_db` has a `require` statement in "lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter" line 13 ([Source](https://github.com/ibmdb/ruby-ibmdb/blob/master/IBM_DB_Adapter/ibm_db/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb#L13))

```
require 'arel/visitors/bind_visitor'
```

However `arel` version 9.0 no longer has this file ([Source](https://github.com/rails/arel/tree/v9.0.0/lib/arel/visitors))

In order for `ibm_db` to work you will need to downgrade rails to version 5.1 which relies on `active_record` 5.1 which relies on `arel` version `~> 8.0` ([Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/activerecord.gemspec))

`arel` 8.0 does have a file "arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb" ([Source](https://github.com/rails/arel/tree/v8.0.0/lib/arel/visitors)) so the require statement will work accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if that was the case, but couldn't find those sources you cited. That's a huge help. Next round's on me.